# Add reference dlls for TFS 2015 Build Automation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015

I'm using TFS 2015 on a local server and Visual Studio 2015. I have a solution that references projects from 2 different repositories.

On the local developer machines, I have the solution and project files references using relative paths:

```
TFS
----Repo1
--------Project1
--------Project2
--------Project3
--------Solution1
----Repo2
--------Project4
--------Project5
--------Project6
--------Solution2
```

Solution1 references Project4 by using ....\Repo2\Project4. This works fine when building the solution locally on VS 2015

Now I'm trying to automate the build in TFS 2015. Since the build definition for Solution1 is inside Repo1, it cannot reference anything in Repo2. So I mapped Repo2 as a folder in Repo1, and built all the projects individually. This worked, all the projects from Project1 to Project6 build individually, except for the last project, which is referencing Project4, Project5 and Project6. I get the following error message:

Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Project4' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried adding parameters to MSBuild Arguments using /p:Reference, /p:ReferencePath, /p:AdditionalLibPaths in multiple ways: This is one attempt:

/p:ReferencePath="$(build.sourcesdirectory)\Repo2\Project4\bin\Debug $(build.sourcesdirectory)\Repo2\Project5\bin\Debug $(build.sourcesdirectory)\Repo2\Project6\bin\Debug"

But it doesn't seem to work.

How do I add references to the missing dlls so my last project can be built?

Thanks

Comment: Typo: Solution1 references Project4 by using ..\..\Repo2\Project4. This works fine when building the solution locally on VS 2015

Comment: Are you talking about two different Git repos in the same team project, or two different TFVC repos spread across two team projects? The answer differs based on which you're using.

Comment: Share the detail build log here or on the OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using TFVC (since you talk about 'mapping' folders), but this answer would be the same for Git:

Use project references instead of assembly references.

Comment: I'm talking about 2 different TFVC Repos.

Comment: So the project file of the top level project is referencing the projects from the other Repo. In the local VS 2015 environment, this is setup using ..\..\Repo2\Project4 and it builds fine. In the TFS 2015 automated build system, it only brings down Repo1 by default, it doesn't get the sources for Repo2 and so the path ..\..\Repo2\Project4 doesn't exist. As a workaround, I mapped Repo2 as a folder inside Repo1. All the projects are being built individually, even the ones inside Repo2. But the top level doesn't seem to find the projects inside the mapped Repo2 folder

Comment: You have to explicitly add workspace mappings for the other team project.